# How to use find / replace for starts with a character than ends with a character

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace, text-formatting

I have 800 line text in my document in Eclipse. I want to format my code like below.

```
Hi hello (how are you?) -> Hi hello

Another example (5895489 hi again) -> Another example
```

as you can see I want to delete  starts with "`(`" and ends with "`)`".

How can I do it in Eclipse with regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following, the replacement value will be an empty value.

```
search: \s*\([^)]*\)
replace:
```

Regular expression:

```
\s*             whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
 \(             '('
  [^)]*         any character except: ')' (0 or more times)
 \)             ')'
```

**Note**: I added the `\s*` to match for leading whitespace just in case so that it don't leave trailing whitespace after the replacement is made.